# what qualities should I be looking for in a long range lens

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon

I am trying to get a long range lens for taking pictures of animals.  I have read many questions and realize I need at least a 300 mm and I know they all depend on price...I'm not to go crazy with price but I would like a very good for wildlife even if it cost more. My question is what brand and I saw some quotes say fast what does that mean? I have a nikon d3000